# Making sure www. is in browser URL bar

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, browser

When I enter my website address, it does not always put www. in front of it.

This is because I type domain.com instead of adding the www. in front as this is quicker.

What code do I have to use to make sure that even if I type domain.com it always adds the www. infront.

(I believe this has to do with .htaccess mod_rewrite function?

Thank you,
Chad.

Comment: Are you using apache?

Comment: You bet (need more characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.htaccess` file, add the following lines (replacing `mywebsite.com` with your real website):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    #redirects all requests to www.mywebsite.com
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mywebsite\.com
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Note that as google [recommands](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=44231) it is better to use a 301 redirection.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Rewrite to www
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```